# Spring IntegrationFlow for multi-tenancy application or multiple folders to watch

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl, file-watcher

Is there a way to register IntegrationFlow for multi-tenancy. Assuming requirement is to process PF for few tenants such as INFY, TCS, WIPRO etc. Every tenant has it’s own directory path with the same pattern like `/mount/batches/{tenantId}/pf`.

Every tenant owns it's own folder as follows:

```
INFY –> /mount/batches/INFY/pf
TCS –> /mount/batches/TCS/pf
WIPRO –> /mount/batches/WIPRO/pf
```

InboundFlow accepting only one source directory and other answers in stackoverflow suggesting to have a separate InboundFlow definition for each folder, but we have almost 100 tenants to configure and for every new tenant we need to have code changes in such case.

Please suggest me, if there any way we can write an adaptor to watch multiple folders at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can programmatically create multiple inbound adapters that send to the same channel.

See [the documeentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.3.0.RELEASE/reference/html/dsl.html#java-dsl-runtime-flows).

With FTP/SFTP you can rotate between different servers and remote folders

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.3.0.RELEASE/reference/html/sftp.html#sftp-rotating-server-advice

There is currently no equivalent for mounted folders.

However, you could configure a custom `DirectoryScanner` that rotates between different folders by delegating to a list of scanners.

Comment: Followed this approach, all the beans were get registered, but not watching the directories they supposed to watch. Do we need to set anything extra after bean registration to monitor the specified folder path.

Comment: It's working fine, forgot to register the bean in integration flow context. Sample `integrationFlowContext.registration(integrationFlow).register();`.